# How do I reference a value in an App Maker query (like I do in Apps Script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I am writing a script to take a stock number, loop through existing stock numbers until a match is NOT found, then assign that unique stock number to the record. My problem is that the usual data[i][2] doesn't seem to reference a 'query' the same way that Apps Script would reference an array.

*Fair warning, I'm trying to expand my Apps Script skills in to broader Javascript so I there's a good chance I'm doing it all wrong - I'm all ears if you tell me I'm doing this all incorrectly!*

Using the log: data[i][2] gives me 'undefined' whereas data[2] gives me all fields of the third item in my query. Based on this I feel like I just need to learn how to reference it properly.

```
//Querying my datasource as 'var data'
var query = app.models.UsedVehicles.newQuery();
query.filters.ParentDealType._contains = prefix;
var data = query.run();
//Returns four records which is correct.

var testStockNo = prefix+month+countstring+year; 
console.log("Test Stock Number " + j + ": " + testStockNo);
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
     console.log("data[i][2]: " + data[i][2]); //results: undefined
     console.log("data[2]: " + data[2]); //results: all fields of 3rd query result.
     if(data[i][2] === testStockNo){
        k++;
        break;
     }else{
     console.log("No Match");
  }
}
```

Even if **testStockNo** equals the value in **field:TStockNo**, the log displays:
Test Stock Number 1: C1200118
data[i][2]: undefined
data[2]: Record : { TIndex: 8, TVin8: HS654987, TStockNo: null, 
         TParentStkNo: GSD6578, TYear: 2010, TMake: NISSAN, TModel: PICKUP, 
         TMileage: 24356, ParentDealType: C}
No Match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue/Solution:

`query.run()` returns array of records and NOT a array of arrays(2D). You should access the `Record` value using it's `key` instead of a `index`.

#### Snippets:

```
console.log("data[i][TStockNo]: " + data[i]['TStockNo']);
console.log("data[i].TStockNo: " + data[i].TStockNo);
console.log("data[2]: " + data[2]);
```

#### References:

- [Query#Run](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/server#Query)

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense now. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!